# Is there any way to append object into the existing array of objects based on the key

Tags: javascript, json

I am having one json object like below,

```
let existing_data = [
       {
          "client":[
             {
                "name":"aaaa",
                "filter":{
                   "name":"123456"
                }
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "server":[
             {
                "name":"qqqqq",
                "filter":{
                   "name":"984567"
                }
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "server_2":[
             {
                "name":"Testing_2",
                "filter":{
                   "name":"567845"
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

This will be dynamic, as of now just gave sample object. If i fill form inputs, will get a object like below,

```
let input_data =  {
      "client":[
         {
            "name":"aaaa",
            "filter":{
               "name":"123456"
            }
         }
      ]
    }
```

I need to append this object into the existing "client" json object. Expected output will be like,

```
[
   {
      "client":[
         {
            "name":"aaaa",
            "filter":{
               "name":"123456"
            }
         },
         {
            "name":"bbbb",
            "filter":{
               "name":"456789"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "server":[
         {
            "name":"qqqqq",
            "filter":{
               "name":"984567"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "server_2":[
         {
            "name":"Testing_2",
            "filter":{
               "name":"567845"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I tried the below method, but it is not working as expected. Some help would be appreciated.

Tried like below and not worked as expected,

```
existing_data.forEach(function (obj) {
  if(Object.keys(obj) == 'client') {
    let old_values = Object.values(obj['client']);
    let new_values = {old_values,input_data['client']};
   }
});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(new_values));
```

Comment: Can you make the existing data an object with properties: client, server, server_2, etc? Or must you leave it such that it is an array of objects, with only one property each?

Comment: in other words could it be like this:
let existing_data = {
          "client":[
             {
                "name":"aaaa",
                "filter":{
                   "name":"123456"
                }
             }
          ],
         "server": [...],
         "server_2": [...],
       }

Comment: why aren't you directly using `existing_data[0]['client'].push(input_data['client'])`

Comment: @GauravSingh that's an input so, the input can have different keys.

Comment: yes correct @code Maniac

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding. But, as you say, you want to enter an object, which is already among the objects in the original array.
The client name `"aaaa"` was already in `existing_data` json. Is that so?

Comment: not name "aaa", need to check whether the "client" array is existing. if it is there, then i need to append the object with existing "client" array. Otherwise need to add new array. am i clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **reduce** and **Object.entries** and **concat** to merge new data with key's respective value

```js
let existing_data = [{"client": [{"name": "aaaa","filter": {"name":"123456"}}]},{"server": [{"name": "qqqqq","filter": {"name":"984567"}}]},{"server_2": [{"name": "Testing_2","filter": {"name": "567845"}}]}]
let input_data = {"client": [{"name": "bbb","filter": {"name": "2345"}}]}
let input_data2 = {"client2": [{"name": "bbb","filter": {"name": "2345"}}]}

function addData(oldData, newData) {
  let [key, value] = Object.entries(newData)[0]
  let found = false
  let modifiedData = oldData.reduce((op, inp) => {
    if (inp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      found = true
      op[key] = inp[key].concat(newData[key])
    } else {
      op = Object.assign(op, inp)
    }
    return op
  }, {})
  
  // return value based on key found in data or not
  return found ? modifiedData : Object.assign(modifiedData, newData)
}

console.log(addData(existing_data, input_data))
console.log(addData(existing_data, input_data2))
```

Comment: This is working, but, if the "input_data" is not present in "existing_data", then we should add that object. Please suggest some solution for that scenario.

Comment: Sorry again, created jsfiddle, please check. Its not appending the new value. I dont know where i am missing. for your refrence, providing the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/13wqjcf2/

Comment: @Deepak you have a different structure in fiddle then you posted in question, here you have one key so i merged accordingly, there you have two keys under single object, so it just merged keys from input data and leaves the other key data,

Comment: yeah correct, actually, fiddle is having correct format. Really Sorry for the  missing the format. Could you please give some solution? Trying for more than 2 days.

Comment: actually, why format is mismatching means, this is dynamic objects and whatever i am getting as response from "addData", function I am passing the same into the function again with another "new input Data". So, please provide some good solution to overcome the issue

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

```
let existing_data = [{
    "client": [{
      "name": "aaaa",
      "filter": {
        "name": "123456"
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "server": [{
      "name": "qqqqq",
      "filter": {
        "name": "984567"
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "server_2": [{
      "name": "Testing_2",
      "filter": {
        "name": "567845"
      }
    }]
  }
];

existing_data.find(function(obj) {
    return "client" in obj;
}).client.push(new_values);

console.log(existing_data);
```

Comment: it is adding one more key to the object, {"client":[{"name":"aaaa","filter":{"name":"123456"}},{"client":[{"name":"aaaa","filter":{"name":"123456"}}]}]}. I need one "client" key, inside that append the new data